# caching plots in R/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Just wondering if there are tricks/ways in which I could cache the plots being generated through our shiny app.

*Background:*

We are doing somewhat compute intensive computations which finally result in  a plot. I am already caching(using memoise) the computations done, globally in shiny but it still takes about .75 seconds to render a plot. I was just wondering if we can decrease that time by removing the time it takes to render an image and if there are slick ways of already doing it.

*More details:*

I am using grid to create the plot(heatmap in this case. Ideally would like the caching to be disk based as storing plots in memory wont scale up.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: See the example at `?renderImage`, it might give you some ideas. Basically you want a memoized plot function that returns a PNG file, I think; and use renderImage to call that memoized function.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Any ideas on how we could get shiny to auto scale static images we render through renderImage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using `ggplot` (which with Shiny, I would bet is a fair assumption).

1. Create an empty list to store your grob, say `Plist`.
2. When a user request a graph, create a string hash based on the shiny inputs
3. Check if the graph is already saved, eg  `hash %in% names(Plist)`
4. If yes, serve up that graph
5. If no,  generate the graph, save the grob to the list, name the element by the hash,  eg,  `Plist[hash] <- new_graph`

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I am using grid for this..just wondering what do you mean by grob and also storing multiple plots in the memory could be expensive and also I would like the caching to be persistent across server restarts. Any packages which caches the plots to disk and render them from there ?

Comment: also wondering do you know of any package which could create a string hash based on input to a function..this would be handy for my case.

Comment: `grob` is just a `graphical object`. You can save them to disk much like any other R object. (see `?saveRDS`).  However, loading them from disk might take just as long as calculating them from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

### Edit

Caching of images created with `renderPlot()/plotOutput()` is supported since shiny 1.2.0.

- release notes: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/upgrade.html
- function documentation https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/renderCachedPlot.html.

The solution below behaves similar to the following usage of `renderCachedPlot()`.

```
output$plot <- renderCachedPlot(
  expr = {
    histfaithful(bins = input$bins, col = input$col) 
  },
  cache = diskCache()
)
```

`renderCachedPlot()` allows caching in memory and on disk with sensible defaults. The rules for generating hash keys can be customized and by default `digest::digest()` is used for all reactive expressions that appear in `expr`.

The solution below demonstrates how a subset of these features (caching on disk) can be implemented with a shiny module. The basic strategy is to use

- `digest::digest()` to create cache keys based on arguments sent to a plot function
- `do.call()` to pass the arguments to the plot function unless the key created  from `digest()` signifies that the image is already cached
- `grDevices::png()` to capture an image from the call to `do.call()` and add it to the cache
- `shiny::renderImage()` to serve images from the cache

### Original answer

Although both answers to this question are very good, I wanted do add another one using [shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). The following module takes a plotfunction and a reactive version of it's arguments as inputs. In the end `do.call(plotfun, args())` is used to create the plot.

```
library(shiny)

cachePlot <- function(input, output, session, plotfun, args, width = 480, height = 480,
                      dir = tempdir(), prefix = "cachedPlot", deleteonexit = TRUE){
  hash <- function(args) digest::digest(args)

  output$plot <- renderImage({
    args <- args()
    if (!is.list(args)) args <- list(args)
    imgpath <- file.path(dir, paste0(prefix, "-", hash(args), ".png"))

    if(!file.exists(imgpath)){
      png(imgpath, width = width, height = height)
      do.call(plotfun, args)
      dev.off()
    }
    list(src = imgpath)
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)

  if (deleteonexit) session$onSessionEnded(function(){
    imgfiles <- list.files(dir, pattern = prefix, full.names = TRUE)
    file.remove(imgfiles)
  })
}

cachePlotUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  imageOutput(ns("plot"))
}
```

As we can see, the module deletes the image files created if needed and gives  the option to use a custom caching-directory in case persistent caching is needed (as it is in my actual usecase).

For a usage example, I'll use the `hist(faithful[, 2])` example just like Stedy.

```
histfaithful <- function(bins, col){
  message("calling histfaithful with args ", bins, " and ", col) 
  x  <- faithful[, 2]
  bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = bins + 1)
  hist(x, breaks = bins, col = col, border = 'white')
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      sliderInput("bins", "bins", 5, 30, 10, 1),
      selectInput("col", "color", c("blue", "red"))
    ),
    cachePlotUI("cachedPlot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    callModule(
      cachePlot, "cachedPlot", histfaithful, 
      args = reactive(list(bins = input$bins, col = input$col))
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Ricardo Saporta is very good and what I used to solve a similar problem, but I wanted to add a code solution as well.

For caching I used `digest::digest()` where I just fed a list of the parameters for that particular graph to that function to create a hash string. I initially thought that I would have to extract the hash string from `observe()` and then use an if/else statment to determine if I should send it to `renderImage()` or `renderPlot()` based on if the image had previously been created. I flailed with this for a while and then stumbled upon just using `renderImage()`. Its not a perfect image substitution but more than close enough for the purposes of this demo.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       sliderInput("bins",
                   "Number of bins:",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 50,
                   value = 25),
      selectInput("plot_color", "Barplot color",
                   c("green"="green",
                      "blue"="blue"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot", width='100%', height='480px')
    )
  )
)
```

and server.R

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output) {

base <- reactive({
  fn <- digest::digest(c(input$bins, input$plot_color))
  fn})

output$distPlot <- renderImage({
    filename <- paste0(base(), ".png")
    if(filename %in% list.files()){
      list(src=filename)
    } else {
    x  <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    png(filename)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = input$plot_color, border = 'white')
    dev.off()
list(src=filename)
    }

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}
```